# AS3 updating selected color with a color picker

Tags: actionscript-3, colors

I am creating a color selector and i've run into a problem. I can get the initial color the picker is already at, but when I click to choose another color the color selected doesn't change.

```
    var r:uint=sliderRed.value;

var g:uint=sliderGreen.value;

var b:uint=sliderBlue.value;

var c:uint=combineRGB(r,g,b);

var ct:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();

     var selectedColor= ct.color=c;
```

here is the part of code that there is trouble with -- so basically I need the selected color to update everytime I click a new color on the color picker. I'm guessing i'm leaving something out, mind giving me some help, i've been at this for days looking for different solutions; Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Stuff all of this into a function and call it from that color picker each time the user updates it. If you have done that already, make sure there's a property of a color picker for its current color, that it's assigned the new value and you are referring to the correct color picker when you request its color.